# Why is Kaspersky's CPU activity not shown in process list?

Tags: process, cpu-usage, task-manager, kaspersky

So, when Kaspersky Internet Security 2011 (11) starts doing a full scan, I can see my CPU activity going to 100%. However, the KIS process only takes 02% according to Task manager, how is this possible? When I quit the scan, CPU activity drops to normal.

Comment: perhaps the AV scan engine is running as a service ?

Comment: @Sathya why not post it as an answer sine I have in fact found a service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps the AV scan engine is running as a service, spawning a child process for the scanning. As @Wil mentioned, I'd recommend you to launch Process Explorer and sort by CPU% when the scan is running, that should give a better idea as to where the CPU is being used.

Comment: Process Explorer seems to attribute about 40% max to the Scan Engine... However the remaining 60% don't seem to show in that nor in other processes... Very odd

Comment: @Blood - Try `View` -> `Show unnamed handles and mappings`

Answer (score 6):

I cannot say for certain, but if it is anything like other Anti Virus programs, it most likely splits the front end application from the back end scan engine.

Make sure you tick the box (or give UAC authentication) in the bottom left hand corner that states `Show processes from all users`.

If you still do not see it, on the `Services` tab, look for the scan engine and right click and choose `Go To Process`. This should you whatever program is associated with that service.

Lastly, if these do not work, I would advise looking at [Microsoft / Sysinternals Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx).

Extra not that helpful lastly, if you are having problems, I would recommend switching to Microsoft Security Essentials. I use it exclusively now and am very happy with it.

Comment: Well I'm not having problems of any kind, I was just curious about why it didn't show the Kaspersky CPU consumption on its process. I'm very pleased with Kaspersky. And I have ticked "Show processes from all users." but still nothing. Also, there are no other processes with that much CPU consumption. Neither the scan engine process nor the front end application process.

Comment: Process Explorer seems to attribute about 40% max to the Scan Engine... However the remaining 60% don't seem to show in that nor in other processes... Very odd